# List comprehension, value if not in second list

Tags: python

Is it possible to use list comprehension to get the sales for each week if the week exists in `sales` else 0?

```
weeks = [{'week': 31}, {'week': 32}, {'week': 33}, 
         {'week': 34}, {'week': 35}, {'week': 36}]
weeks = [x['week'] for x in weeks]

sales = [
    {'week': 32, 'sales': 1167.26}, 
    {'week': 33, 'sales': 1373.61}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 1491.43}, 
]

expected = [0, 1167.26, 1373.61, 0, 0, 1491.43]
```

Comment: Are all of the items in `sales` guaranteed to have a matching item in `weeks`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh In the example they don't.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes all `sales` weeks must exist in `weeks`

Comment: Will they always both be sorted?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes, sorted

Comment: will week value be always unique in the sales list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay to use third party libraries like pandas

```
import pandas as pd
weeks = [{'week': 31}, {'week': 32}, {'week': 33}, 
         {'week': 34}, {'week': 35}, {'week': 36}]
df1=pd.DataFrame(weeks)    

sales = [
    {'week': 32, 'sales': 1167.26}, 
    {'week': 33, 'sales': 1373.61}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 1491.43}, 
]
df2=pd.DataFrame(sales)

df1.merge(df2,how='left').fillna(0)
```

Output

```
week    sales
31      0.00
32      1167.26
33      1373.61
34      0.00
35      0.00
36      1491.43
```

In case you have multiple entries in the sales list for same week

```
import pandas as pd
weeks = [{'week': 31}, {'week': 32}, {'week': 33}, 
         {'week': 34}, {'week': 35}, {'week': 36}]
df1=pd.DataFrame(weeks) 

sales = [
    {'week': 32, 'sales': 1167.26}, 
    {'week': 33, 'sales': 1373.61}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 1491.43}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 5}, 
]
df2=pd.DataFrame(sales)

pd.DataFrame(df1.merge(df2,how='left').fillna(0).groupby('week')['sales'].sum(name='sales'))

week    sales
31      0.00
32      1167.26
33      1373.61
34      0.00
35      0.00
36      1496.43
```

Inspired by @Ajax1234's solution, in case you have multiple values in sales for one week you can create a dict with grouped values

```
weeks = [{'week': 31}, {'week': 32}, {'week': 33}, 
         {'week': 34}, {'week': 35}, {'week': 36}]
sales = [
    {'week': 32, 'sales': 1167.26}, 
    {'week': 33, 'sales': 1373.61}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 1491.43}, 
    {'week': 36, 'sales': 5}, 
]

sales_dict={}
for i in sales:
    if i['week'] in sales_dict:
        sales_dict[i['week']]=sales_dict[i['week']]+i['sales']
    else:
        sales_dict[i['week']]=i['sales']
[sales_dict.get(i['week'],0) for i in weeks] # sales_dict= {32: 1167.26, 33: 1373.61, 36: 1496.43}
```

Output

```
[0, 1167.26, 1373.61, 0, 0, 1496.43]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary from `sales` to use as a lookup for each week in `weeks`:

```
weeks = [{'week': 31}, {'week': 32}, {'week': 33}, 
     {'week': 34}, {'week': 35}, {'week': 36}]

sales = [
{'week': 32, 'sales': 1167.26}, 
{'week': 33, 'sales': 1373.61}, 
{'week': 36, 'sales': 1491.43}, 
]
_sales = {i['week']:i['sales'] for i in sales}
results = [_sales.get(i['week'], 0) for i in weeks]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1167.26, 1373.61, 0, 0, 1491.43]
```

Comment: I liked the solution but what will happen if sales list has multiple entries for the same week. I know OP has not clarified this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you guarantee there is only one element of `sales` for any given `week` value, you can obtain a sequence of sales values which you sum over to obtain the values for any given week:

```py
out = [
    sum(sale['sales'] for sale in sales if sale['week'] == week)
    for week in weeks
]
```

If there are multiple entries in `sales` for any given `week` number, their results will be summed to produce an aggregate value of the sales output.

This gives you a single list comprehension with the desired output:

Output:

```py
[0, 1167.26, 1373.61, 0, 0, 1491.43]
```

Comment: `sum(sale['sales'] for sale in sales if sale['week'] == week)` is a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Say, create an intermediate mapping of week number to sales, something like

```
week_sales = {s['week']: s['sales'] for s in sales}

expected = [week_sales.get(w['week'], 0) for w in weeks]
```